# Minimum distance between two elements in a circular array

Tags: javascript, math

Given a circular array, what is an efficient way to determine the minimum distance between two elements?

For example moving from here

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

To here

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Is more convenient from the outer bounds, whilst moving from here

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

to here

```
[0,0,0,1,0,0]
```

is more convenient internally.

My initial idea was this:

```
sourceLocation = rotatorElements["pos"].indexOf(1);
targetLocation = rotatorElements["pos"].rotate(delta).indexOf(1);

var D = Math.abs(targetLocation - sourceLocation);
var O = Math.abs(rotatorElements["pos"].length - D);

if ((D - O == 0)) direction = 1;
else {
    if (D < O) direction = -1;
    else direction = 1;
}
```

Note: `rotate` rotates the circular array by a defined number of positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I think I answered the question in the title, but what you want is a direction not a distance. Then:

```
function getDirection(from, to, array) {
    if (from === to) {
        return 0;
    }
    var internal = (Math.max(from, to) - Math.min(from, to) < array.length/2) ? true : false;
    if (internal && from < to
       ||
       !internal && from > to
    ) {
       return 1;
    } else {
       return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so you can take a look on github
https://github.com/Andres75/roundcarousel/blob/master/rotate.html

around line 258

Answer (score 7):

Calculating the absolute distance between the elements is useful:

```
var dist = Math.abs(targetLocation - sourceLocation);
```

Then you can just check if it's more or less than half the length of the array. If the distance is more than half the length, it's closer to wrap around:

```
if (dist < rotatorElements["pos"].length / 2) {
  // move internally
} else {
  // wrap around
}
```

#### Edit:

I pasted the code together:

```
function move(sourceLocation, targetLocation, length) {
    var dist = Math.abs(targetLocation - sourceLocation);
    var direction = sourceLocation < targetLocation ? 1 : -1;
    if (dist < length / 2) {
        console.log('internally, direction =', direction);
    } else {
        console.log('wrap, direction =', -direction);
    }
}

move(5, 0, 6);
move(5, 3, 6);
```

Output:

```
wrap, direction = 1
internally, direction = -1
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bUCmk/

Comment: Just testing it, give me a sec...
I posted it on github: 
https://github.com/Andres75/roundcarousel/blob/master/rotate.html
around line 258, the elements should rotate in the direction relevant to the closest object.

I put your code in it

Comment: @user2347441: Moving internally only means that you move in one specific direction if the target always is to the left of the source (or vice versa), but then you wouldn't need to use `Math.abs` to get the distance between them in the first place. You can use `(sourceLocation < targetLocation ? 1 : -1)` to calculate the direction when moving internally, and if you wrap around the direction is reversed.

Comment: just tried that one but still it doesnt behave correctly...
i'll try and post it on jsfiddle.

Nope, cant' put it there... need modernizr and a plugin...

Comment: @user2347441: I don't know what you did with the code. I put it together in a demo above.

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution (in groovy) that gives you the direction and the distance (move is counterclockwise if output is negative):

```
def move(def start, def target, def length){
    def clockwise
    def counterclockwise
    if (start > target){
        clockwise = length - start + target
        counterclockwise = start - target
    } else {
        clockwise = target - start
        counterclockwise = length - target + start
    }
    if (counterclockwise < clockwise){
        return counterclockwise * -1
    }
    return clockwise
}
```

And this is the output:

```
groovy:000> move(0,0,0)
===> 0
groovy:000> move(0,0,4)
===> 0
groovy:000> move(0,1,4)
===> 1
groovy:000> move(0,2,4)
===> 2
groovy:000> move(0,3,4)
===> -1
groovy:000> move(1,0,4)
===> -1
groovy:000> move(1,1,4)
===> 0
groovy:000> move(1,2,4)
===> 1
groovy:000> move(1,3,4)
===> 2
groovy:000> move(2,0,4)
===> 2
groovy:000> move(2,1,4)
===> -1
groovy:000> move(2,2,4)
===> 0
groovy:000> move(2,3,4)
===> 1
groovy:000> move(3,0,4)
===> 1
groovy:000> move(3,1,4)
===> 2
groovy:000> move(3,2,4)
===> -1
groovy:000> move(3,3,4)
===> 0
```